# Create after insert trigger which updates record by getting value from other Oracle 11g table

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have two tables

```
Parent(id, name, occupation)

Child(id, name, gender,parent_id, parent_name, parent_occupation)
```

Now to insert value in child i'll run chi query

```
insert into Child(id,name,gender,parent_id) values(10,'XYZ','Male',15);
```

So now my requirement is when this insert query is executed a trigger will run and get name and occupation from parent table for id 15 (parent_id of the Child record) and add it to the newly inserted row in fields parent_name and parent_occupation respectively.

I am using Oracle 11g as my database.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The parent_name and parent_occupation are an attribute of the parent, they belong in the parent table, not the child..

Comment: @MatthewWatson, they are already in the `PARENT` table. As the two tables are linked via `CHILD.PARENT_ID` the two columns in the `CHILD` table are redundant. I agree the OP needs to review their schema design!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something akin to this (though you'll need to add code to handle the exception):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER ai_child_tg
AFTER INSERT ON child
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT name,
          occupation
     INTO :NEW.parent_name,
          :NEW.parent_occupation
     FROM parent
    WHERE id = :NEW.parent_id;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_data_found
   THEN
        <handle_your_exception_>
END ai_child_tg;
```

However, if your `CHILD` table is really a relational child to your `PARENT` table and there is a FK relationship in place (via the `CHILD.PARENT_ID` column) then storing the `PARENT_NAME` and `PARENT_OCCUPATION` columns in the `CHILD` table is logically redundant.

I'd query why you have those two columns in the `CHILD` table at all.

Hope it helps...